# Multiple Button Selectors Jquery

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-selectors

I've a webpage that's going to have multiple sections which allows the user to make selections and build up a shopping basket based on their selections.

The following code works perfectly when there is only one section, however when there are multiple sections the jquery affects all the buttons as they are currently the same class name.

```
var stg1Butt = $(".stg1_butt");
//Disable Button Function
$(function () {
    stg1Butt.on('click', function (val) {
        //.not Remove elements from the set of matched elements, so removes the button clicked from element
        stg1Butt.not(this).prop("disabled", true);
        var section = stg1Butt.not(this).parents(".section-item");
        section.css({
            "opacity": "0.5"
        });
        var p = $('#calculator p').addClass('calc-content');
        $(p).text($(this).val());
        $('.tck_bx').css({
            "visibility": "visible"
        });
    });
});
//Clear and Enable Button Function
var clr_butt = $(".clr_butt");
clr_butt.on('click', function () {
    if ((stg1Butt).is(':disabled')) stg1Butt.prop("disabled", false).css({
        "opacity": "1"
    });
    var section = stg1Butt.parents(".section-item");
    section.css({
        "opacity": "1"
    });
    $('.tck_bx').css({
        "visibility": "hidden"
    });
    var p = $('#calculator p');
    $(p).empty().removeClass('calc-content');
});
```

What i'm hoping to do is to essentially have a universal function that can be used over and over that will detect what button has been clicked and then disable all other buttons within that container div. Ideally i'd do it using siblings to grab all buttons on the same level but i'm not able to do that due to my div structure.

However i'm struggling on just how exactly to put it together. Any advice will be appreciated.

Below is my div structure.

```
<div id="bnk_stck" class="stg1-section-item">
    <img src="img/stage_one/stck_img1.png">
    <p></p>
    <div class="stg1-section-button">
        <input type="button" name="bnk_butt" value="Button1" class="stg1_butt" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I only see 1 button, where are the others? Also not sure what you are trying to do here? The eventListeners should work for all the elements that have the class you use as a selector.

Comment: So you have multiple sections, a button is clicked in any one (or more) of them to select items and at some point, user adds all to cart simultaneously?

Comment: putvande Each section has about eight buttons in so i didnt want to copy too many in...yes @alou that is correct, the value of each button is added to the cart when they click on the individual button. What i want to avoid is writing the same function x amount of times for each section. Thanks

Comment: I cant understand the logic, why not having a button with a class="thebutton" and data-prodictID="15" and then an on click handler function, passing the product id to the cart? You say you add one product at a time so that's one way to do it

Comment: @alou yes that makes sense, however the problem im having is not to do with adding products, it's to do with been able to disable all other buttons within each individual section when a button from that section is clicked.  

So when a button is clicked it should disable all other button elements within the section, ideally i would select them using siblings however because of my structure i'm not able select them using that method. Sorry if i've not been clear.

Comment: OK then I think Derek's answer + .attr('disabled', true) in the end should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You my consider this selector

```
$(this).closest(".stg1-section-item").find(".stg1_butt").not(this)
```

to select everything in the section.  I do have this selector working in a fiddle. I took some liberties with your html to match what was described.

http://jsfiddle.net/6KD2k/

Answer (score 0):

Its a little weird but you can do this:

```
$(".stg1_butt").on("click", function(evt){
  var clicked = $(evt.currentTarget);
  $(".stg1_butt").prop('disabled', true);
  clicked.prop('disabled', false);
});
```

The only thing that makes it weird is disabling then enabling the target.  If you have unique id's on the buttons you can get past that though.